# Two click at the same time

Tags: ios, swift

How to prevent the calling of two function if the user press two UIButton at the same time?

Suppose to connect two IBAction to two UIButton.
If the user press simultaneously both print are called.
Is that a code not thread safe?

```
@IBAction func firstAction(sender: AnyObject) {
print("first")
}
@IBAction func secondAction(sender: AnyObject) {
print("second")
}
```

Comment: These functions will run on the main thread and so they will run one after the other.

Comment: oh yes sorry. So I need only to add a condition to check if other button is pressed. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best idea would be to set exclusive buttons

You can put it in viewdidload:

```
  yourButton.exclusiveTouch = true
```

I think this is much more elegant than putting mass if conditions.

Cheers :)